# Using leaflet-react Markers with options and Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-leaflet

I am using the default markers of react-leaflet and added custom properties to the markers.

```
<Marker icon={trash} key={element["_id"]} databaseid={element["_id"]} extrainfo={element["locationname"]}
                            position={[Number(element["lat"]), Number(element["long"])]}
```

However, TS is telling me now:

```
Property 'databaseid' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & MarkerProps & RefAttributes<Marker<any>>'
```

How can I extend the type-definition of this marker? I have googled around StackOverflow but have not got my head quite around it.